# Position search ItemClick arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, searchview

Good evening,
I am creating an application about traffic legislation in my country, Activity with RecyclerView and SearchView when clicking on any cell brings me a new intent with the information of the chosen cell, however when searching a certain word returns item from position 185 when clicking on the desired option returns cell information from position 0, follow my code for help, should the onCLick position not be reset and a new count be made?
How do I solve this?
Thanks.

[Item 185 after the research.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjVAM.png)

[Information obtained from position 0 and not from 185.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skZe1.png)

**EnquadramentoActivity.java**

```
private RecyclerView recyclerViewEnquadramento;
private List<EnquadramentoModel> listaEnquadramentos = new ArrayList<>();
private List<EnquadramentoModel> listaEnquadramentosFiltrado = new ArrayList<>();


private AdapterEnquadramento adapter;
private DatabaseReference referencia;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enquadramento);

    referencia = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    recyclerViewEnquadramento = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewEnquadramento);
    
    this.criarEnquadramentos();
    
    adapter = new AdapterEnquadramento(listaEnquadramentos);
    
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerViewEnquadramento.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerViewEnquadramento.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewEnquadramento.setAdapter(adapter);

    recyclerViewEnquadramento.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplication() ,recyclerViewEnquadramento, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DetalhesEnquadramentoActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("tituloFirebase", listaEnquadramentos.get(position).getTituloFireBase());
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        @Override
        public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
        }
    }));
}

private void criarEnquadramentos() {
    DatabaseReference dados = referencia.child("legislacao").child("Enquadramento");

    dados.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot valores: snapshot.getChildren()){
                EnquadramentoModel enquadramento = valores.getValue(EnquadramentoModel.class);
                listaEnquadramentos.add(enquadramento);

            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}

private void filter(String text){
    List<EnquadramentoModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (EnquadramentoModel item : listaEnquadramentos){
        if (item.getTipificacao_resumida().toLowerCase().contains((text.toLowerCase()))){
            filteredList.add(item);
        }
    }
    adapter.filterList(filteredList);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem((R.id.action_sarch));
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**AdapterEnquadramento.java**

```
private List<EnquadramentoModel> listaEnquadramentos = null;
private ArrayList<EnquadramentoModel> arrayList;
private String tituloFirebase;

public AdapterEnquadramento(List<EnquadramentoModel> listaEnquadramentos){
    this.listaEnquadramentos = listaEnquadramentos;
    this.arrayList = new ArrayList<EnquadramentoModel>();
    this.arrayList.addAll(listaEnquadramentos);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemLista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_enquadramento, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemLista);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    EnquadramentoModel enquadramentoModel = listaEnquadramentos.get(position);
    holder.artigo.setText(enquadramentoModel.getArtigo());
    holder.tipificacao_resumida.setText(enquadramentoModel.getTipificacao_resumida());
    tituloFirebase = enquadramentoModel.getTituloFireBase();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listaEnquadramentos.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView artigo, tipificacao_resumida;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        artigo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textArtigo);
        tipificacao_resumida = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tipificacao_resumida);

    }
}

public void filterList(List<EnquadramentoModel> filteredList){
    listaEnquadramentos = filteredList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**RecyclerItemClickListener**

```
 private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);

    public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position);
}

GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && mListener != null) {
                mListener.onLongItemClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { }

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent (boolean disallowIntercept){}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use onItemTouchListener to handle recyclerview item click event.
Here in your adapter you can handle click directly in adapter something like this:

```
private List<EnquadramentoModel> listaEnquadramentos = null;
private ArrayList<EnquadramentoModel> arrayList;
private String tituloFirebase;

private OnItemClickListener listener;

public AdapterEnquadramento(List<EnquadramentoModel> listaEnquadramentos){
    this.listaEnquadramentos = listaEnquadramentos;
    this.arrayList = new ArrayList<EnquadramentoModel>();
    this.arrayList.addAll(listaEnquadramentos);
}

// do not forget to set the listener in fragment/activity
public void setListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemLista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_enquadramento, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder viewHolder  = new MyViewHolder(itemLista);

    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listener.onItemClick(view, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });
    viHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        public void onLongClick(View view) {
            listener.onLongItemClick(view, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    })

    return viweHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    EnquadramentoModel enquadramentoModel = listaEnquadramentos.get(position);
    holder.artigo.setText(enquadramentoModel.getArtigo());
    holder.tipificacao_resumida.setText(enquadramentoModel.getTipificacao_resumida());
    tituloFirebase = enquadramentoModel.getTituloFireBase();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listaEnquadramentos.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView artigo, tipificacao_resumida;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        artigo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textArtigo);
        tipificacao_resumida = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tipificacao_resumida);

    }
}

public void filterList(List<EnquadramentoModel> filteredList){
    listaEnquadramentos = filteredList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

please note that I do not test this code, but above implementation is based on your original code in the question. Please adjust it accordingly.